# Performance test for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

I've developed a framework for web applications that heavily depends on JavaScript and JQuery and i'm facing big performance issue in the client processing specially when handling some UI changes... and because i am using many JavaScript libraries i will not be able to pass on every JavaScript function,callback and event handler to check each performance.

Is there any way to detect the specific functions that causes long time processing to be able to optimize them or even replace them?

Comment: Look into profilers. Chrome ships with a nice one: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: Plugin Y-slow would work as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Profile function in Chrome developer tools or Firebug, that will give you an overview of every function called, the stack and the running time.